# Derivative of $\int_0^x(f(u) \cdot u)\,\mathrm{d}u$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

I have two integrals that I want to calculate its derivative:

$$\int_0^x(f(u) \cdot u)du ~~~~~ , ~~~~~ \int_0^x(f(u))du$$

So from what I understand: $[\int_0^x(f(u))du]'=f(x) \cdot 1 \cdot x = x \cdot f(x)$

But how do I calculate the second one? It should be equal, but I do not understand why.

EDIT:

I have $G(x)=\int_0^x(f(u)(u-x))du$ which is equal to $\int_0^x(f(u) \cdot x)du-\int_0^x(f(u) \cdot u)du$

And because $x$ is constant here, we have $x \cdot \int_0^x(f(u))du-\int_0^x(f(u) \cdot u)du$

And I want to find $G'(x)$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(u) \, du = f(x).$$  This is the second fundamental theorem of calculus ( https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html ).

Applying this to $u f(u)$,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x u f(u) \, du = x f(x).$$

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong. Since $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xh(u)du=h(x)$, the answers are $xf,\,f$. You may have been thinking of $\int_0^xf(x)du=f(x)\int_0^xdu=xf(x)$.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful!